# Salesforce JAVA streaming client TransportExchange error

Tags: integration, streaming-api

I have created salesforce streaming client around three months ago using following doc : http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_streaming/index.htm
Now the updated doc is using  cometd/31.0 but as of before I am using following streaming end point :
**STREAMING_ENDPOINT_URI = "/cometd/30.0";**

This streaming client was running fine as a background process.

But after 2014-09-06 05:00 it has stopped working with following error message :

```
{"message":[{"id":"59","connectionType":"long-polling","channel":"/meta/connect","clientId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}],"id":"59","exception":"java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected response 503: TransportExchange@942038940=POST//<salesforce url>/cometd/30.0/connect#7","successful":false,"channel":"/meta/connect"}
```

After sometime(~3 min) I started getting this message :

```
{"message":[{"id":"77","connectionType":"long-polling","advice":{"timeout":0},"channel":"/meta/connect","clientId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}],"id":"77","exception":"java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected response 401: TransportExchange@1989841081=<salesforce url>/cometd/30.0/connect#7","successful":false,"channel":"/meta/connect"}
```

Now this java client is still running as a background process but not responding anything.
Now I have killed this java client and started it again and everything started working fine with following connection message from salesforce :

```
[CHANNEL:META_CONNECT]: {"id":"5","successful":true,"channel":"/meta/connect","clientId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
```

**But I am still not getting the reason of the issue at first place.
 Anyone have any idea about this or What can I do to avoid this issue in future ?**

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem. I even attempted to reconnect, but I continued to have this error until I restarted the client. The critical question here is who how the recovery works for topics once a network issue takes place in the middle of the processing of messages. I have looked around, but there is no specific example there.
    I will let you know if I figure something out. Please do the same if you were able to resolve your problem.
    Best,

```
      Eduardo.
```

Comment: have you found anything yet ? I have got the same problem once again on 14th Feb 2015 but no resolution apart from restarting the client .